# iframe to fill remaining visible space over different platforms

Tags: html, css, iframe

I know similar questions have been asked before, but my question is relating to how the iframe is shown on different platforms.

I have a header `<div>` and then an iframe `<div>` immediately below. the header is a logo so that is set to `width=100%` (incidentally the height of this is static so I can define that if needs be).

My issue is with the iframe; how can I make it fill the remaining space of the ***visible*** screen space (ie no blank space below and also no scroller bar)? I *could* just find the height of the header and do calculations for the average screen size, but I want it to be more methodical than that, and also if it was somehow possible to do this based on % values then im presuming it would automatically resize to give the same result on tablets, etc... Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it with %
example: suppose height of header is 150px

```
.your-iframe-div {
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

not sure if mozilla supports this function now,, but if it doesnt:

```
.your-iframe-div {
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Comment: if mozilla doesnt support it, do I include both, or just the latter?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but my best guess is that you should put both. The reason I am saying this is that browsers now comment out the parts of css that are re-written or mistaken. So basically if the first one doesnt work out for firefox, it will be commented out.